# Sort columns and output result based on conditions

Tags: google-sheets

Help me create a formula to find the latest negative number in column F that corresponds to the latest date in column D that can be called using the corresponding value in column E. If no result is found, output "Not Applicable." The table looks like this:

[image]

In the table above, if I call Text3, the output should be -25,899.68.

Answer (score 2):

*You may test:*

```js
=let(Σ,filter(D:F,E:E="Text3",F:F<0), Λ,index(Σ,,1),
       ifna(chooserows(filter(index(Σ,,3),Λ=max(Λ)),-1),"Not Applicable"))
```

Comment: if I want to use ABS to make the number positive, how do I insert that in this formula?

Comment: before `chooserows` part

Comment: nifty! thank you!!